# Convert SwiftUI Color to UIColor

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift5

I want to convert SwiftUI view Color to UIKit UIcolor component. I have tried several ways and also refer the StackOverflow already given answers, But they did not work. It was also mentioned by some users in those posts. I have gone through the below code which is proposed by [turingtested](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3776782/turingtested)

but this is not working. Any suggestions or help is really appreciated.

```
fileprivate extension Color {
    func uiColor() -> UIColor {
        let components = self.components()
        return UIColor(red: components.r, green: components.g, blue: components.b, alpha: components.a)
    }
    private func components() -> (r: CGFloat, g: CGFloat, b: CGFloat, a: CGFloat) {
        let scanner = Scanner(string: self.description.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.alphanumerics.inverted))
        var hexNumber: UInt64 = 0
        var r: CGFloat = 0.0, g: CGFloat = 0.0, b: CGFloat = 0.0, a: CGFloat = 0.0
        let result = scanner.scanHexInt64(&hexNumber)
        if result {
            r = CGFloat((hexNumber & 0xff000000) >> 24) / 255
            g = CGFloat((hexNumber & 0x00ff0000) >> 16) / 255
            b = CGFloat((hexNumber & 0x0000ff00) >> 8) / 255
            a = CGFloat(hexNumber & 0x000000ff) / 255
        }
    return (r, g, b, a)
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly does “this is not working” mean? Does it not compile? Does it crash? Does it give wrong results?

Comment: It works for `Colors` you declare like this: `Color(red: 0.74, green: 0.5, blue: 0.32)`, but not for static ones like `Color.red`

Comment: That "solution" should never be used, it attempts to derive color components from the object's `description`... it can break at any moment.

Comment: I think self.description prints "red" for a Color.red

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basically, Apple doesn't intend for you to do this conversion. SwiftUI's `Color` is a `View`, and the design of the framework is that data flows to a `View`, which is  then displayed. You are never supposed to extract data back from a `View`.

If you find yourself needing to use the components of a color, you should work with `UIColor`, and then convert to `Color` at the time you are ready to display it.

If you are trying to get the components of system colors like `Color.red`, I believe they are the same as the adaptive `UIColor.systemRed`, which does have accessible components.

[Standard Colors](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/standard_colors) documentation

Comment: Though I follow the logic, it's still so frustrating we can't just move away from UIColor. It seems heavily redundant.

Answer (score 34):

If you are looking for an up-to-date answer:

From iOS 14 onward, the `UIColor` class has an initializer, which takes a SwiftUI color as argument: `UIColor(Color.red)`.

Comment: What should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

Update your answer to this to get rid of the long tuple warning and it works fine.

```
extension Color {
    func uiColor() -> UIColor {
        if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
            return UIColor(self)
        }

        let scanner = Scanner(string: description.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.alphanumerics.inverted))
        var hexNumber: UInt64 = 0
        var r: CGFloat = 0.0, g: CGFloat = 0.0, b: CGFloat = 0.0, a: CGFloat = 0.0

        let result = scanner.scanHexInt64(&hexNumber)
        if result {
            r = CGFloat((hexNumber & 0xFF000000) >> 24) / 255
            g = CGFloat((hexNumber & 0x00FF0000) >> 16) / 255
            b = CGFloat((hexNumber & 0x0000FF00) >> 8) / 255
            a = CGFloat(hexNumber & 0x000000FF) / 255
        }
        return UIColor(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: a)
    }
}
```